# How to scroll with class name only using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I scroll down or up by class name in selenium with python?

I found this element:

```
<div data-is-here-when="md lg" class="left-sidebar js-pinned-left-sidebar ps-relative" id="left-sidebar">
    <div class="left-sidebar--sticky-container js-sticky-leftnav">
```

[image: take a look here please :D]

Comment: Its not with python

Comment: why my question are closed? i didn't find an answer, and ther's no This question already has answers here: